# Unsure why out of bounds exception is happening

Tags: java, debugging, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Getting an out of bounds exception but do not understand why. My recursive function calls itself each time removing an item from the array list till its empty. Once its empty the row should be filled and then we add the values back to the list. I think on the final element it throws an exception because of the list length, it does not want to delete last element. Is there any way around this? Is there any chance it is a different error?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][]board=new int[9][9];
    Solver solve = new Solver();
    ArrayList<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
    Collections.shuffle(choices);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 9; j++) {
            solve.fill(board, choices, i, j);
        }
    }
    }
}

class Solver {

public void fill(int board[][], ArrayList<Integer> choices, int 
row, int col) {
    int num = choices.remove(0);
    if (isValid(board, row, col, num) == false) {
        fill(board, choices, row, col);
    } else
        board[row][col] = num;
    return;
}


public boolean isValid(int board[][], int row, int col, int num) {

    if (checkRow(board, row, col, num) == true) 
            /*checkCol(board, row, col, num) == true)*/
        /*checkSqr(board, row, col, num) == true*/
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean checkRow(int board[][], int row, int col, int num) {
    boolean valid = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 9) {
        if (board[i][col] == num) {
            return valid = false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

expected result would be the board [][] being populated randomly according to the sudoku rules. 
instead we get 
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
        Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at Solver.fill(Solver.java:31)
    at Main.main(Solver.java:22)

Comment: unrelated question: why import `Array`, `Collections`, and `Random` by name if you're also importing every single thing in `java.util`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you still have an element before calling `int num = choices.remove(0);` you could use [`List.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty--) like

```
if (choices.isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
int num = choices.remove(0);
```